# git fetch - no way to get local branch updated

Tags: git

This is something I never faced before. While trying to get a full copy of a remote repo, **some folders remain empty whatever I try.**

**Locally :**

```
$ cd path/to/repo
$ git init
$ git remote add origin ssh://remote_repo/.git/
$ git fetch
$ git checkout -t origin/master
```

Files correctly downloaded and uncompressed, but... not all the remote files.

**On the remote server  :**

```
git status
On branch master nothing to commit (working directory clean) 
cd path/to/problematic_folder
ls
//returns expected folders and files
```

**Locally**

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ cd path/to/problematic_folder
$ ls
//returns empty folder
```

**Another try to update just in case**

```
$ git fetch origin master
remote_repo password:
From remote_repo
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

$ git pull origin master
remote_repo password:
From remote_repo
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

I'm not strong at all with git, but I always do the same basic things, and never had such problem before. Of course now if I download manually the missing files, my local branch diverges from remote...

How can I solve that issue ?

## EDIT 2

At least 2 other folders react the same, and worst, if I edit a file of these folders directly in the remote repo, changes aren't tracked (working dir. clean). No way to add these dir to git !

## EDIT

Since I can get the files manually (ftp), **if I do so to gain time, how can I harmonize then local and remote repos state/history ?** Thank you

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore`?  Make sure that the path you're having trouble with isn't listed in that file.

Comment: Would there be a reason for those files to be [ignored](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)? Check for `.gitignore` files, or `.git/info/exclude` in the remote repo.

Comment: Thanks. I did already. `.gitignore` doesn't refer to that path and no path at all in `.git/info/exclude`

Comment: Any chance that folder is part of a submodule?  Does a `.gitmodules` file exist anywhere in the project?

Comment: Indeed there's another  `.git ` and  `.gitignore ` in that folder. It was a part of antoher module I moved there. But I've just deleted these 2, to check, it doesn't seem to solve that issue :(

Comment: Are there still two `.git`s in the remote branch though?

Comment: Indeed? still there. But I did setup that repo once before, and I had done something to declare the sub `git`. Now I could either delete it

Comment: Alright, bring your local repo back to the remote state.  Then go into the directory with the second `.git` and run `git pull`

Comment: Also, when you clone it - is `.git` the only thing in that directory?

Comment: Just done that. returns already up-to-date. and what do you mean y the only thing in the dir ? there's a bunch of files...

Comment: What about my edit purpose ? Since I can get the files manually (ftp), if I do so to gain time, how can I harmonize then local and remote repos state/history ? Thank you

Comment: My recommendation if you do that is to store the files you're editing elsewhere while you're fixing git, then copy them back and commit when everything is working again.  Having a difficult time figuring out exactly what's going on without looking at it, so that's the safest solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88113/discussion-between-nickentin-and-kojo).

Comment: Did you try `git clone` instead of `git init && git add remote ... && git fetch && git checkout`. You initial setup process seems rather complicated.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I tried to clone the repo, but it comes without the "phantom" folder. I also realised that at least 2 other folders react the same, and worst, if I edit a file of these folders directly in the remote repo, changes aren't tracked (working.. clean). No way to add these dir to git ! I'm about to reinitialize the repo and lose the full history...

Comment: If you repo got broken at some point in time, maybe you can just fetch the changes up to this point (if you have an idea when the problem happened). Maybe you can preserve some of our history. Or you write a script that stepped through the whole history, copies the files after each commit to local and commit (to replay the whole repo). This are just some ideas... Not sure if this is feasible.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasJ.Sax. I ended re initializing the repo...